# React - how to show array length from result of the other array process

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I want to show array length from result of the other array process.
I have one array contain 3 objects and want to get the failed result property length.

Code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            arrays: []         
        };
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.getData();
    }

    getData = () => {
        const arrays = [
            {
                name: 'one',
                value: '1',
                result: 'failed'
            },
            {
                name: 'two',
                value: '2',
                result: 'success'
            },
            {
                name: 'three',
                value: '3',
                result: 'failed'
            }
        ];
        this.setState({
            arrays : arrays
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { arrays } = this.state;
        console.log(arrays);
        console.log('arrays length: ' + arrays.length);

        const fArray = [];
        console.log(fArray);
        console.log('fArray length: ' + fArray.length);

        return (
            <div className='App'>
                {arrays.map(function(array) {                    
                    if (array.result === 'failed') {
                        const failed = {
                            fName: array.name,
                            fValue: array.value,
                            fResult: array.result
                        }
                        fArray.push(failed);
                    }
                    return null;
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

console result :

[image]

At the picture above why the first `arrays` and `fArray` show 0 length?

The second `arrays` shows 3 length and `fArray` shows 0, but it have two failed results.

I mean, can i get the two failed results length from `fArray`?

Please tell me if my post is duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `console.log(fArray);`, your `fArray` is actually empty. So the result is 0. You populate the `fArray` in your `map`.Why don't you just use the filter feature

```
<div className='App'>
    {arrays.filter(a => a.result === 'failed').map(item => {
      // do what you want with failed items
    })}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you show me how to get the length result of you code above? i need the length result of 'failed'.
I tried to `return console.log(item.length)` from your code but the result is undefined.

Comment: `arrays.filter(a => a.result === 'failed').length` like that ?

Comment: With your code above, how to show the length? i tried to change the `.map` to `.length` but shows `TypeError: arrays.filter(...).length is not a function`. Sorry i'm really new for this.

Comment: Mr. Striped, Thank you very much. I tried to make a variable and use the `arrays.filter` than console.log it.